# Function Returns Byref

Tags: vb.net, function

Can a function return a value byref instead of the default byval?  That is to say, allow me to directly edit the variable that it is retrieving instead of just giving me a copy of that variable.

Right now I'm trying to write a function that will return, based on what the user has selected through a combobox, a particular setting (eg. My.Settings.somethingHere).  I then want to be able to edit the setting directly through just calling the function.  Is that at all possible?

```
private function myFunction() as byte
  select case comboBox1.text
     case "a"
       return my.settings.a
     case "b"
       return my.settings.b
  end select
end function

private sub something()
  myFunction() -= 1
end sub
```

Comment: That requires a pointer, poorly supported in managed code in general, completely unsupported in VB.NET.  A simple alternative for this code is `Sub AdjustSetting(ByVal adjustment As Integer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function can't return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962371/vb-net-is-object-returned-by-reference-from-function) reference of byte instead you may create property (Writable) to assign value.

```
 Public WriteOnly Property Change As SByte
        Set(value As SByte)
            Select Case comboBox1.text
                Case "a"
                    My.Settings.a = value
                Case "b"
                    My.Settings.b = value
            End Select
        End Set
 End Property
```

and assign value to Change property,

```
private sub something()
  Change -= 1
end sub
```