# Does any .net language support returning ref type

Tags: .net, clr

In one of his [blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx) Eric Lippert said:

> Finally, the CLR does allow “ref return types”; you could in theory have a method “ref int M() { … }” that returned a reference to an integer variable. If for some bizarre reason we ever decided to allow that in C#

Does either VB or F# support this? I was thinking of various ways to do strongly typed properties collection, without using reflection...

**UPDATE:** as of [C#7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

According Eric Lippet - C# does support this feature.

> it is entirely possible to create a version of C# which supports both
>   these features. You could then do things like

```
static ref int Max(ref int x, ref int y) 
{ 
  if (x > y) 
    return ref x; 
  else 
    return ref y; 
}
```

> and then call it with

```
int a = 123;
int b = 456; 
ref int c = ref Max(ref a, ref b); 
c += 100;
Console.WriteLine(b); // 556!
```

you can read more on his answer to a question regarding return ref types in C#:

[Why doesn't C# support the return of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339602/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-the-return-of-references)

As for you question about VB - the language doesn't support it:

> **Return By-Reference?**
>
> Although functions can pass variables by reference, they cannot return
>   them that way. When a function returns, its local variables do not
>   exist anymore (or are pending cleanup if they are heap-allocated).
>   Functions therefore always return by value; because the local
>   variables don't have valid memory addresses anymore, there aren't any
>   variable references to return.
>
> Putting it all together, when you return an object from a function,
>   the only thing that is copied is the address of the object. When you
>   return a value type from a function, the value itself is copied.
>
> This means reference types are essentially value types, wherein the
>   value is the memory address of an object on the heap, (or Nothing)

Source: [VB.NET, Is Object Returned by Reference from Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962371/vb-net-is-object-returned-by-reference-from-function)

I couldn't find the same info for F# but I guess it will be the same as VB - so the answer - you can't return ref in F#.

Comment: Thank you for the references.  I will note that Eric said it was possible to build a version of C# that did this, and that he had done so, not that C# as shipped supported it. Also, hoodaticus's answer, while seeming to addess this issue is in answer to an entirely different question.  Still, usefull for the links.

Comment: Right, you have misinterpreted what I said.  I built a private test version of C# that had that feature, to prove that it could be done. We decided to not actually do it in the real product.